# magmi - not able to import/assign product to there categories

Tags: magento-1.7, magmi

I am trying to import products via magmi all the other attributes are imported , but I am not able to assign those products to there categories. (I have already enabled On the fly category creator/importer). but still I am not able to figure out why the products are not getting assigned to the categories.

here is the snippet of my csv file

> store,attribute_set,type,tax_class_id,sku,name,description,weight,status,visibility,price,special_price,special_from_date,special_to_date,use_config_manage_stock,custom_range,custom_catalogue,item_type,color,color_specific,custom_lead_time_message,news_from_date,news_to_date,giftboxed,discontinued,discontinued_text,release_date,size_text,related_keyword,category_ids,media_gallery,image,small_image,thumbnail,options_container,bundle_skus,sku_type,weight_type,price_type,price_type,product_attr_brand,product_attr_range,product_attr_pattern,product_attr_group,product_attr_group_item,product_attr_size,product_attr_imp,product_attr_met,product_attr_cap_imp,product_attr_cap_met,product_attr_pres_met,product_attr_pres_imp,product_attr_warranty,product_attr_carton_pcs,product_attr_carton_vol_metric,product_attr_carton_vol_imp,product_attr_carton_wt_metric,product_attr_carton_wt_imp,product_attr_item_wt_metric,product_attr_item_wt_imp,product_attr_barcode_code128,product_attr_barcode_ean13,product_attr_carton_dim_metric,product_attr_carton_dim_imp,product_attr_size_range,product_attr_cap_range,product_attr_colour,product_attr_material,product_attr_shape,custom_warranty_time,websites,new
>   Default,Default,simple,2,11010043ysys,"Simplicity: Sake/Condiment Cup 4.5cl (1.6oz) - Simplicity White","Sake/Condiment Cup",0,1,"Catalog, Search",9.99,,,,1,,,,White,White,No,,,0,0,,,,,,,,,,container1,,,,"Use config","Use config","Steelite Performance",Simplicity,"Simplicity White (1101)",Accessories,"Sake/Condiment Cup","4.5cl (1.6oz)",,,,,,,Y,12,"0.0173 cu. m","0.61 cu. ft","1.15 kg","2.54 lb","0.059 kg","0.13 lb",0105018461394748,5018461394748,"408 x 319 x 133 mm","16.1 x 12.6 x 5.2 inches",,,White,"Alumina Vitrified",Round,,"base,europe02,americas01",0
>   Default,Default,simple,2,11010114ysys,"Simplicity: Rimmed Soup Plate - 23cm (9"") 44cl (15.5oz) - Simplicity White","Rimmed Soup Plate",0,1,"Catalog, Search",9.99,,,,1,,,,White,White,No,,,0,0,,,,,128,,,,,container1,,,,"Use config","Use config","Steelite Performance",Simplicity,"Simplicity White (1101)",Bowls,"Rimmed Soup Plate","23cm (9"") 44cl (15.5oz)","9""","23 cm","15.5 oz","44 cl",,,Y,24,"0.0173 cu. m","0.61 cu. ft","14.24 kg","31.39 lb","0.581 kg","1.28 lb",0105018461000144,5018461000144,"264 x 244 x 268 mm","10.4 x 9.6 x 10.6 inches","7.1"" to 9""",,White,"Alumina Vitrified",Round,,"base,europe02,americas01",0
>   Default,Default,simple,2,11010115ysys,"Simplicity: Soup Cup Lugged - 28.5cl (10oz) - Simplicity White","Soup Cup Lugged",0,1,"Catalog, Search",9.99,,,,1,,Tableware,"Alumina Vitrified",White,White,No,,,0,0,,,,,"189,1386",,,,,container1,,,,"Use config","Use config","Steelite Performance",Simplicity,"Simplicity White (1101)",Bowls,"Soup Cup Lugged","28.5cl (10oz)","5.63""","14.4 cm","10 oz","28.5 cl",,,Y,36,"0.0519 cu. m","1.83 cu. ft","12.4 kg","27.34 lb","0.326 kg","0.72 lb",0105018461000151,5018461000151,"525 x 385 x 257 mm","20.7 x 15.2 x 10.1 inches","7"" or under","5.1oz to 11oz",White,"Alumina Vitrified",Round,,"base,europe02,americas01",0

not sure what I am doing wrong here ? does the data inputs I have passed to category_ids cell is in correct format ?

Thanks in advance.